# How to generate an object out of proto map

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, proto, protoc, grpc-web

I have following proto that defines a dictionary map, when converting to typescript this type is returned as an array of tuples `Array<[string,string]>` however I would like it as an object of key:value pairs. Is it possible? Should I use different type on the proto side?

```
message Dictionary {
    map<string, string> pairs = 1;
}
```

To generate web output and typescript types I'm using grpc-tools protoc.exe with `--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary` and `--grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext`

Comment: I'm having the same issue, you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation suggests you should use `getPairsMap()` on your `Dictionary` message:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#map

That then has a `toObject` function:

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/8080bebf1f2ff87ef96a24135afe7f82d2eb3d2a/js/map.js#L148

I've not tried this.

Comment: There are no difference between `getPairsMap().toArray()` and `getPairsMap().toObject()` both return `[string,string][]`. Which is weird I think, looking at the object returned by `getPairsMap` there is a field `_map` that is the one I would like to get out of it, but can't find a way to get it. There is a `forEach` method that I can use to populate object `const pairs:Record<string,string> = {}; getPairsMap().forEach((entry: string, key: string):void=> { pairs[key]=entry; });`